# Python date conversion in JSON format

Tags: python, datetime-format

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I have a column in my table that has DateTIme values. It stores the datetime like this 2017-02-17 00:00:00 but when I am getting the value using python jsonify() function I am getting it like this Fri, 17 Feb 2017 00:00:00 GMT

What do you suggest I do. I want the value to be in the format it is in the database and not changing it to a string date time.

Comment: I **THINK** the way to go would be creating your own [json_encoder](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.json_encoder) (assuming you are using flask). Here is an example how to do that : [LINK](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/119/)

Comment: If you want to do it the raw python way, you could use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to get a datetime object and then use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to convert to the proper format. Might or might not be an overhead depending on your situation

Comment: Basically how do I convert Fri, 17 Feb 2017 00:00:00 GMT to 2017-02-17 00:00:00 in Python